# ¿Como configurar el path para geckodriver en Ubuntu?

Tags: django, ubuntu, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Me encuentro haciendo un tutorial de TDD en Django y selenium. 
estoy usando Ubuntu 
y la primera parte es correr el siguiente codigo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox() 
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
assert 'Django' in browser.title
```

cuando ejecuto el archivo me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functional_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/home/jorge/Documents/envdjango/gogoat/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 142, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/jorge/Documents/envdjango/gogoat/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory
```

por lo que entiendo el error es de selenium que falla en encontrar el geckodrive, he tenido algunas aproximaciones (intenté esto https://askubuntu.com/questions/870530/how-to-install-geckodriver-in-ubuntu)

estoy corriéndolo todo en un virtualenv y estas son las versiones que da `pip freeze`:

```
Django==1.11.2
selenium==3.4.3
Ubuntu==16.04.2 LTS
```

Answer (score 0):

Que tal,

En python podrías intentar esto

```
binary = FirefoxBinary('path/a/geckodriver')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

En java yo lo hago de la siguiente forma, podrías buscar como establecer la propiedad en python (como alternativa a lo de python):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path/a/geckodriver");
```

Otra opción es la siguiente:

1. Descarga el geckodriver: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
2. descomprime y copia el archivo en alguna ruta.
3. en la terminal pega el siguiente comando cuidando de cambiar el "[ruta-donde-esta-el-geckodriver]"

   export PATH=$PATH:/[ruta-donde-esta-el-geckodriver]/geckodriver

Comment: Hola! gracias por contestar, me temo que soy supernuevo en linux y no se muy bien como ingresarlos, serian en el py shell? podrias explicarme que es lo que pasa? gracias de nuevo

Comment: Sólo descarga el geckodriver y pegalo en una ruta, luego reemplaza esa ruta por lo que dice C:\\geckodriver.exe

Te añadí unas opciones más.

Comment: sigo intentandolo, pero no funciona me sigue dando el mismo error. lo intenté con export 

PATH=$PATH:/[/home/jorge/Downloads/gecko]/geckodriver

me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jorge/Documents/envdjango/gogoat/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver'

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functional_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/jorge/Documents/envdjango/gogoat/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: que pasa si solo escribes en tu terminal geckodriver?

Comment: @jfergt lo que van obteniendo al intentar nuevas cosas, puedes ponerlo en tu pregunta, editándola (usa el enlace editar). Leer o interpretar un log puesto en los comentarios no es exactamente fácil para nadie y puesto en la pregunta (como un Edito: probé xyz y obtuve este error: xxxxx) es mucho más legible.